# Keep the Content after the AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I in my project am using `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true`, for when the user scrolls there is a transparency in the **AppBar**.

But I have a problem with how I can put the content after the **AppBar** and keep the transparency when I scroll.

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 1),
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        extendBody: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text(
            'O que visitar',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(11, 95, 119, 1),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.9),
          iconTheme: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme,
        ),
        drawer: const DrawerWidget(),
        body: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
       
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I've already tried the **SafeArea** works but when scrolling the **AppBar** has no transparency

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use extendBodyBehindAppBar, your body takes the whole screen height and body seems to appear behind Appbar. So in this case you can apply padding in top as kToolBarHeight + (your specific top padding)

```
const EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolBarHeight + 16)
```